# Tarball a specfic number of files

Tags: linux

I have a huge directory containing thousands of files. If I create a single tar.bz2 with all of them, it generates a cumbersome 8GB file, so when I need to bzcat it, it takes quite long.

Is there any way to create multiple tar files containing, say, a thousand files each?

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think the split command wouldn't really work because it may split a single file in two parts, one of each in a different tarball.

Any suggestion would be REALLY welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
i=0;
j=0;
for f in *
do
    j=$((j+1))
    if [ $((($j) % 1000)) == 0 ]
    then
        i=$((i+1))
    fi
    tar -rf $i.tar $f
done
```